# Concatenating two TIME columns in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server-2012

I want to concatenate two `TIME` columns and show as one column.

Example:

- FromTime: 9:00
- ToTime: 12:00

Result should be:

```
9:00-12:00
```

Comment: what is datatype of `'fromtime','totime'`

Comment: what _RDBMS_ ? is this for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic SQL:

```
-- hh:mm:ss
SELECT 'result:' + CONVERT(CHAR(6), FromTime, 8) + '-' + CONVERT(CHAR(6), ToTime)
    FROM yourTable
```

MySQL:

```
-- hh:mm
SELECT 'result:' + DATE_FORMAT(FromTime, '%H:%i') + '-' + DATE_FORMAT(ToTime, '%H:%i')
    FROM yourTable
```

SQL Server:

```
-- hh:mm
SELECT 'result:' + convert(char(2), DATEPART(hh, FromTime)) + ':' + 
    CONVERT(CHAR(2), DATEPART(mm, FromTime)) + '-' +
    CONVERT(CHAR(2), DATEPART(hh, ToTime)) + ':' + 
    CONVERT(CHAR(2), DATEPART(mm, ToTime))
    FROM yourTable
```

Comment: +1 for the `generic sql` the best i can use when a OP dont mention the _RDBMS_

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @FromTime time  
declare @ToTime time

set @FromTime='9:00'
set @ToTime='12:00'


select cast(@FromTime as varchar(10))+ '-' + cast(@ToTime as varchar(10)) as result
```

### <kbd>[sql demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/552d2/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `convert`

```
select convert(VARCHAR(5),getdate(),108) + ' - ' + convert(VARCHAR(5),getdate()-1,108)
```